# addHostedAttachment error in Google Site with UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anybody know if there is a new limit for attaching files in a Google Site page with aps script ?

A simple example doesn't work anymore for large files :

Steps to reproduce :
1.Create a UiApp with the code below
2.Run the script in a Google Site
3.Select a small file (<1MB)
4. Result is ok, file attached.
5. Run again with a larger file (>2.6MB), 
6. Result is NOK :"error encountered : an unexprected error occurred"

Source code : 
function doGet(e) {

```
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload File to Site"); 
   var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
   formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile')); 
   formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton("Click to upload")); 
   var form = app.createFormPanel(); 
   form.add(formContent); 
   app.add(form); 
   return app; 
 } 

 function doPost(e) { 
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget 
   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile; 
   SitesApp.getActivePage().addHostedAttachment(fileBlob); 
 }
```

This worked before, not since a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was is a known change in behavior and the team is working on resolving this.

Here is the Issue Tracker item to check -

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2723